# Visualize a nested JSON structure

Tags: javascript, css, json, responsive-design, data-visualization

Consider this JSON object :

```
{ department_1 : [{ id : 1, name = Joe Smith, email : jsmith@usf.edu}, ...., { id : 500, name = Bun Sam, email : bsam@usf.edu}]}
{ department_2 : [{ id : 1, name = Joe Smith, email : jsmith@usf.edu}, ...., { id : 500, name = Bun Sam, email : bsam@usf.edu}]}
{ department_3 : [{ id : 1, name = Joe Smith, email : jsmith@usf.edu}, ...., { id : 500, name = Bun Sam, email : bsam@usf.edu}]}
{ department_4 : [{ id : 1, name = Joe Smith, email : jsmith@usf.edu}, ...., { id : 500, name = Bun Sam, email : bsam@usf.edu}]}
```

Obviously this is a nested data structure, and there are many records, in this example in the deepest level we have about 2000 records. what is the best way to visualize this in a responsive and interactive manner. I have already used the table, and it doesn't look that interactive. I am looking for ideas and approaches, and maybe some sample implementations to visualize this taking the usability into account.

Comment: Also what type of data you want to make interactive.. like numbers can look interactive in graphs but strings dont so...

Comment: I would go for an interface similar to the one offered by LINQPad (a tool for running C#). It has a nice way of visualizing potentially large object graphs, in which sub-objects can be collapsed/expanded. See screenshot here: https://code.google.com/p/linqpadvisualizer/

Comment: @VirajNalawade I am looking for something that is interactive, and self presented. I would like to represent data in a way that is using the least amount of textual data. Take the example I have given, as the user enters the page he is faced with 4 shapes that represent each department, clicking on each shape will eliminate 3/4 of the other data, and then presents the user shape each representing the element of an array within that department.

Comment: @w0lf this will be eventually a web app so front-end technologies is needed.

Comment: @EasyQuestions I know. I just proposed a conceptual way of doing it in case you don't find an existing solution. If I had an implementation that does what you want, I would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @EasyQuestions: Were you able to find a solution for the above problem statement? I am also looking for such visualization functionality..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Collapsible Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) using d3.
(selected out of [their gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery))

They have a well documented example on the page.

Comment: this is very close to what I am looking for it nicely shows the nested data structure, and it is interactive, but I have that implemented already and would like a more modern approach using interactive databins. please read my comment above.

Comment: @EasyQuestions interested in if you were able to find a better solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice visualization of nested tables.  It isn't interactive, but you could make it so by converting the text areas to `<textarea>`:

http://bl.ocks.org/nautat/4085017

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a tree view that looks similar to Regedit

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0):

I created a json viewer and editor library. you can try it here: https://guifier.com/json
if you like the library please dont forget to star it on github: https://github.com/maliknajjar/guifier
and this is the library on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/guifier

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34838657)

Answer (score -1):

Try Chart.js. You can find a lot of examples and tutorials online.

Here is the documentation link
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: chart.js doesn't have any charts to represent the nested data strcuture in the way that I need. Please read my comments under the question.